# How to put string label on X axis in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using scatter plot from d3 and I'm trying to label x axis of the plot with string which I can read from a csv file.

Here is my code for current implementation:

```
var xValue = function(d) { return d.age;}, // data -> value
    xScale = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]), // value -> display
    xMap = function(d) { return xScale(xValue(d));}, // data -> display
    xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient("bottom");

var yValue = function(d) { return d["income"];}, // data -> value
    yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]), // value -> display
    yMap = function(d) { return yScale(yValue(d));}, // data -> display
    yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left");

d3.csv("predict_plot_h1b.csv", function(error, data) {
    // x-axis
    // Y-axis

    // Other D3 elements

});
```

this gives me something like (Only x axis labels are important in plot below):

[image]

This is what my csv data looks like:

```
age, income
72, 2
50, 1
55, 3
50, 2
80, 2
```

So over here i want to use exact age labels instead of using range from 50 to 80.

How can i modify my code so that X axis label appear as ***50   55   72   80*** instead of ***50  60  70  80***

Comment: `xAxis.tickValues(data.map(function(d) { return d.age; }).unique().sort())`

Comment: I tried using this but I get following error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined` I also tried to define xAxis inside function where i load data which gives me different error.

Comment: You need to run this once the data has been loaded, i.e. inside the callback.